# Проверка условия в TextView

Tags: java, android

Возник вопрос, как правильно проверить условие в TextView?
В TextView приходит число 1 или 2, но как проверить их?
Я еще учусь, не судите строго.
Мой кусочек кода с условием

```
public void Prov()
    {
        num = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Number);

        if (num.getText().toString() == 2 || num.getText().toString() != 1)
        {
            showDialog(DIALOG_EXIT);
        }
        else if (num.getText().toString() == 1 || num.getText().toString() != 2)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Все хорошо", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Условие проверки строки на true такое

```
if (num.getText().toString().equals("1")) {}
```

Если проверка на false то

```
if (!num.getText().toString().equals("1")) {}
```

Или получить число (но рискуете нарваться на исключение при вводе букв)

```
if (Integer.parseInt(num.getText().toString()) == 1) {}
```